# Flutter BLoC - Bloc vs Cubit event driven state management advantages

Tags: flutter, bloc, clean-architecture, flutter-bloc, event-driven-design

### What are the **actual** advantage(s) of Bloc over Cubit?

In addition to **traceability** (which you can also achieve with appropriate logging in Cubit), and **advanced event transformations** (I can't think of any "advanced" event transformations that Cubit can't do, since there is always a way to do it with Cubit. And if you're using clean architecture, domain/data layer can help with complex data manipulations).

#### Sharing and sourcing events

These are the things that I'm looking for that should be able to do with Bloc since these things can't be actually done with Cubit. However, it appears that these are impossible (or is it?) because adding event on a Bloc requires you to identify the actual Bloc where the event will be added. `bloc.add(YourEvent())`.

Also, event sharing is somewhat debatable because this can lead to a bad architecture/hard to maintain.

For event sourcing, I can't find in the docs if this is possible (reversing back to a specific past state?).

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know reversing to past state can be easily done when you have immutable states regardless of whether it is bloc or cubit. Having immutable states allows you to store list of states and restore whenever you need a specific state.

Bloc has no advantages over cubit but rather different purpose. In cubit you have action=>response (function=>states) whereas in bloc you have streams.

**What cubit cannot do?**

For example you can have two events being processed concurrently when using bloc [(since bloc 7.20)](https://verygood.ventures/blog/how-to-use-bloc-with-streams-and-concurrency) but you cannot call two functions simultaneously on cubit.

**Sharing events**

You can share events implementation between different blocs because you have to specify what events bloc implements.

```
class MyBlocA extends Bloc<MyEvents, StatesA>

class MyBlocB extends Bloc<MyEvents, StatesB>
```

If I understood correctly, what you want to do is to process a single event in two different blocs, which you cannot do because event is emitted to a specific bloc. So it requires two calls:

```
blocA.add(EventA);
blocB.add(EventA);
```

Depending on your case you might listen to state of MyBlocA inside MyBlocB. This way whenever event for MyblocB appears, the action would depend on the state of MyBlocA.

Comment: I think concurrency is what Cubit can do that Bloc can't do before 7.20 since you can just call 2 methods and they will be processed concurrently. 7.20 supports concurrency for Bloc as well. (It was also on the link).

Sharing events, if I'm just going to call the blocs that are needed to act on the event, then it is not an advantage also since you can just call multiple cubit functions also. They also don't scale well since each time a new bloc(s) is/are added on the same event, you need to call the new bloc(s).

Comment: Since you are correct that they are immutable, I believe that the reversing of a previous state is advantageous for both of them. Thinking of different purpose instead of having bloc an advantage over cubit might be the right way to go. Lastly, I don't consider listening bloc from a bloc directly since overall I think it is a bad architecture.

Comment: This is great info. The Github repo of the library also suggests that you "start with Cubit until you need to refactor into a Bloc". I've used this suggestion as a rule of thumb on many projects now and it has served me quite a lot. Don't be afraid to refactor, developing software is usually closely tied to that, and improving it usually means you will do refactoring here and there.

Comment: Also, regarding Bloc to Bloc communication, I understand your preference since I used to think like that as well. I changed my mind when I started noticing that sometimes you might need state information from one Bloc in another separate one. One example of this might be needing `user` from `AuthBloc` in a separate bloc like `ProfileBloc`. Of course, you could just send the state by accessing context on when providing `ProfileBloc` but then you might run into synchronization issues between the state of `user` in `AuthBloc` and `user` in `ProfileBloc`; especially if your op changes `user`.

Answer (score 1):

`Bloc`s and `Cubit`s are same in terms of state management with only one difference of state mutation: `Bloc` is event driven and `Cubit` is method driven.

Apart from all of this, in terms of architecture not much is different as of now. All others have been mentioned precisely by @chris in the above. It is up to the developer on how to maintain the state in a way is manageable for us.

Comment: I agree, I'm looking for a solid justification to use the Bloc's event-driven design, instead of by personal preference only, since it is much harder to appreciate and learn by new developers. Maybe I'll for more answers. Thanks btw.

Comment: I've been an avid BLoC user since past one and half year. I've never used Cubit. We two are polar opposites in terms of usage. I've always been an asynchronous event-driven guy so I understand why you are looking for answers. I hope you find the best answer, one that will be of your usage.

Answer (score 0):

aren't events for dependency injection?

**Cubit**

1. call **Action**
2. set **State**

**Bloc**

1. trigger **Event** (inject something, depending on screen/page it was trigger from. as Example)
2. then call **Action**
3. and set **State**

Comment: I don't think dependency injection is relevant here, Event driven programming is like a queuing system to be handled by consumers. Events being queued up from the view (being emitted), then the bloc class respond on the events accordingly.